# declare a 2d matrix in python including random numbers but after that it should not be changed

Tags: python, matrix, random

I need a matrix in python including random number as its elements. But these elements shouldn't be change in multiple run:

```
 myMat=np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5,5))

 [[9 5 1 4 3]
 [2 1 5 9 3]
 [9 2 7 8 4]
 [5 7 2 7 2]
 [9 0 8 0 8]]
```

I need a random matrix just to start my code. After that no change should be happen. I tried '.seed()' method but it looks it doesn't work in case of 2d matrixes.

Answer (score 2):

`np.random.seed()` works.  As long as you use the same seed the same matrices will be generated:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(1)
>>> np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5,5))
array([[5, 8, 9, 5, 0],
       [0, 1, 7, 6, 9],
       [2, 4, 5, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 7, 7, 9],
       [1, 7, 0, 6, 9]])
>>> np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5,5))
array([[9, 7, 6, 9, 1],
       [0, 1, 8, 8, 3],
       [9, 8, 7, 3, 6],
       [5, 1, 9, 3, 4],
       [8, 1, 4, 0, 3]])
>>> np.random.seed(1)                      # reset to same seed
>>> np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5,5))     # same first matrix
array([[5, 8, 9, 5, 0],
       [0, 1, 7, 6, 9],
       [2, 4, 5, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 7, 7, 9],
       [1, 7, 0, 6, 9]])
>>> np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5,5))     # same second matrix
array([[9, 7, 6, 9, 1],
       [0, 1, 8, 8, 3],
       [9, 8, 7, 3, 6],
       [5, 1, 9, 3, 4],
       [8, 1, 4, 0, 3]])
```

To maintain over multiple runs of a script you'll have to save the initial seed in a file or something.  For example on the first run check for the existence of the file, pick a seed and save it.  Later runs the file exists and initialize the seed from the file.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. what is the point of '1'? why it should be passed to the seed method?

Comment: @mohamadbari You can use any number.  Different numbers will generate different pseudorandom numbers.  Re-seed with the same number and generate the same pseudorandom numbers

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to cast the arrays to lists, which wouldn't change after initial declaration.

```py
import numpy as np

my_mat = [list(arr) for arr in np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5,5))]
```

**Edit:** I tested this out, and it doesn't appear that the random arrays change after they're initially stored, so casting shouldn't be needed. The following worked for me.

```py
import numpy as np

my_mat = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5,5))

print(my_mat)
print()
print(my_mat)
print()

for n, arr in enumerate(my_mat):
    for i, arr2 in enumerate(my_mat):
        if i == n:
            print(arr)
            print(arr2)
    print()
```

#### Result

```
[[4 6 5 2 1]
 [7 5 2 6 6]
 [3 6 2 2 1]
 [0 6 8 5 4]
 [1 5 6 2 4]]

[[4 6 5 2 1]
 [7 5 2 6 6]
 [3 6 2 2 1]
 [0 6 8 5 4]
 [1 5 6 2 4]]

[4 6 5 2 1]
[4 6 5 2 1]

[7 5 2 6 6]
[7 5 2 6 6]

[3 6 2 2 1]
[3 6 2 2 1]

[0 6 8 5 4]
[0 6 8 5 4]

[1 5 6 2 4]
[1 5 6 2 4]
```